# How to change a custom query into a standard loop?

Tags: wp-query, loop, wpdb, template-tags

I'm trying to modify how results are displayed in a post list that's currently controlled by the code below. However, it's not built in the WP_Query `while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();` style I'm accustomed to and have built a lot of shortcodes and loop styles around.

How can I change the code below into a "regular" Wordpress loop that will allow me to use template tags like the_title()?

```
    $totalposts = $wpdb->get_results($querystr, OBJECT);
    $wp_query->request = $querystr . " LIMIT " . $ppp . " OFFSET " .$offset;
    $results = $wpdb->get_results($wp_query->request, OBJECT);
    foreach ($results as $result) {
        $offset++;
        $output .= '<a href="'.get_post_permalink($result->ID).'">' . $result->post_title . ' (' . $result->post_date . ')</a><br>';
    }
```

Comment: What are the query params?

Comment: this really depends on whats in `$querystr`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to be able to use template tags, you have to do two things after getting your custom select query:

1. You have to declare the `global $post` variable.
2. You have to call the setup_postdata($post) function to populate the variables.

So, my code had to be changed like so:

```
$results = $wpdb->get_results($wp_query->request, OBJECT);
global $post;
foreach ($results as $post) {
    setup_postdata($post); 
?>
<h4><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h4>
```

etc.

The key to this is on this codex page:

[Displaying posts using a custom select query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Displaying_Posts_Using_a_Custom_Select_Query)

Answer (score 1):

How I have done custom queries in the past is use `$wpdb->get_col()` and just returned an array of IDs of the posts. Then I pass that to a `get_posts()` passing the IDs to the `post__in` parameter. That way you can then use WP standard controls.